Is it possible to render pdf to report viewer winforms?
From the question above, I am trying to render a pdf file using my customize report viewer. Is it possible to render a pdf without installing from any 3rd party?
In the meantime I use webbrowser controls to render pdf however. my goal is to use a customize report viewer to disable the print button.

.rpt files contain connections, data sources, and a layout that maps the data source to the visual report. Why would you think you can use a .PDF as a source for Report Viewer? You can export an .rpt rendered in Report Viewer to a .PDF, but you can't "jam a .PDF into Report Viewer".
